# jquery fixed div on scroll, bottom boundary

Tags: php, jquery

**Fixed version with smooth movement: http://jsfiddle.net/66MBH/6/**

i have been looking everywhere, but been unable to find anything that could help me,
To start with,
 
Jquery code.(cant remember where i got it)

```
    $(document).ready(function () {  
  var top = $('#socialbookmarks2').offset().top - parseFloat($('#socialbookmarks2').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
  $(window).scroll(function (event) {
    // what the y position of the scroll is
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (y >= top) {
      $('#socialbookmarks2').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
      $('#socialbookmarks2').removeClass('fixed');
    }
  });
});
```

**Quick**; How do i make this stop when the container's /div have been reached?, a bottom boundary or something?

**Expained**;
I'm using the code on a custom "blogging" website, simular to a wordpress blog, the socialbookmarks are supposed to follow each blog post from the top to the bottom of the post and then starting over for the next post when the user have scrolled to it,

Right now, if i activate it, it works on the first bookmarks-container(#socialbookmarks2) that then follow all the way down to the bottom of the page instead of stopping at the end of the post.
 
There are 10 posts on each page.
Hope its understandable.. 

**I have found somthing simular to what i want it to do if you look at [9gag.com](http://9gag.com), If you see their rating and twitter/facebook sharing box. it follows the post and then stops at the bottom of it.**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately your answer is to just add another statement to your condition:

```
if (y >= top && y < bottom) {
  $('#socialbookmarks2').addClass('fixed');
} else {
  $('#socialbookmarks2').removeClass('fixed');
}
```

now, what is bottom? top + the height of your element. Since I don't know what that element is I can only give a crude example:

```
<div class="blog-item">
    <div class="social-bookmarks"></div>
    <h1>blog title</h1>
    <p>
        content here
    </p>
</div>
```

You would need to consider the parent of the social bookmarks. additionally, the listener has to be on class and not id.

```
var bottom = y + $(this).parent().height();
```

assuming this is in a loop for each $('.social-bookmarks') evaluation.

There are many ways to write this out. I am just pointing out a way to achieve your effect as a theory and not a working example. For that, you would need to try it out and I may update if needed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response!
I have been trying to make it work on the site but it wont do anything and just stops working, i have made a simple jsfiddle to show how it looks right now, without your code, could you possibly try to add your code and see if it works? sorry for the trouble, i'm not so good at all this js stuff yet.
http://jsfiddle.net/7KcJb/1/
 thanks very much :)

Comment: It's not a matter of adding code. It's restructuring your code to not rely on an element with an id, and considering the item's height as a restriction. I updated the fiddle with a basic point in the right direction: http://jsfiddle.net/7KcJb/3/ - it works for me but with a little display glitching. Nothing you can't work out with a little effort.